# getting some unwanted text as part of velocity template Velocity+Camel+Email

Tags: apache-camel, velocity, email

I am trying to send an email using velocity template.

I am getting unwanted text as part email as highlighted below before actual text in .vm template

```
) CamelInterceptedEndpoint: smtp://jinkala.prasanthi%40ge.com@SMTP.trans.ge.com?password=******* contentType: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Hello,

Message ERROR Alert: Tue Feb 09 16:21:36 IST 2016with ERROR Code:6060911 of could not deliver.

Error in DB-Operation:CannotGetJdbcConnection :Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied ) Exception: ---------- Message: Test Mail Please do not reply. It is system generated mail.
```

Not sure why i am receiving this. Please suggest me.

Comment: The error says `invalid username/password; logon denied`. Have you looked into that? Are you absolutely sure you're using a proper user/pass combo?